# Change (not init) a UIBarButtonItem identifier programmatically?

Tags: iphone, uibarbuttonitem

In IB I can set the identifier of a UIBarButtonItem to 'play' which adds an image of a play button (right-pointing triangle).

Is there a way to change this image programmatically?  I want to change it to 'pause' when the play button is pressed.

I know you can initialize a UIBarButtonItem with an identifier but I've yet to find a way to change it after it's been initialized.  Is this even possible?

The only thing I can think of is to remove the old button and initialize a new one in its place, but this hardly seems efficient.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok I've googled this question to death and ran into [sample code from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/avTouch/Introduction/Intro.html)  where they do exactly the same thing (toggle play/pause button graphic on a toolbar button).  But instead of using the built in play and pause identifiers of `UIBarButtonItem` they use a custom `UIButton` and toggle custom images.

So if Apple goes through the trouble of creating and toggling custom images on a UIButton instead of the built in play and pause `UIBarButtonItem` buttons then I think it's pretty safe to say there's no way to programatically change the identifier of a `UIBarButtonItem`.

This is what they (Apple) do to toggle the images when the button is pressed:

```
// Call this when the button you want to toggle is pressed:
[playButton setImage:((p.playing == YES) ? pauseBtnBG : playBtnBG) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Replace p.playing with whatever BOOL you want to hold the state of your button.  `playButton` is the custom `UIButton` in the toolbar.  `pauseBtnBG` and `playBtnBG` are the images to toggle.

Answer (score 13):

This seems to work fairly well:

```
UIBarButtonItem *oldButton = [myToolBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
[myToolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[myToolBar objectAtIndex:0], [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemStop target:self action:@selector(tapStopRefreshButton:)],nil] animated:NO];
[oldButton release];
```

In this example I had a toolbar for a UIWebView and when someone clicked Reload I wanted it to change to Stop. The toolbar only had a flexible space and the one button on it - to right-align the button - so I grabbed a reference to the old button, made a new one with the same selector as the old, reset the buttons on the tab bar, and then released the original button.

Not the prettiest, but you can use all standard buttons without having to override the button class(es).

Comment: Apple does this in the StitchedStreamPlayer example: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/StitchedStreamPlayer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010092

Comment: Whilst technically not 'changing' the `UIBarButtonSystemItem` as the OP is after, this answer does allow the *replacement* of one system item with another.

Comment: Although, in this example, the new `UIBarButtonItem` should be initialised before being put into the array, so it can be properly released.

Comment: Why do you need to grab and release the old button? I see no reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

What about 2 stacked toolbars? Then you can have some system buttons in the top one, and others in the bottom one. If the play button is pressed, then just hide the top toolbar.

Comment: He's looking to change the image or swap the button, not have a tool bar vanish.

Comment: @JoshDM However if the tool bar vanishes, the button shown to the user will change. Furthermore, in these cases normally you have not one, but a set of buttons that you have to change so I find easier to have two different toolbars with standard UIBarButtonItem's instead of creating and toggling custom UIButtons. Also is easier to 'hide' a view. But you're right is not the answer to the question, it's an answer to the asker problem.